# Questions about SAML login in WSO2is: Disable Consent Page, claims include in response

Tags: saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2is 5.5 in a saml environment (Service Provider is using pac4j). My User Store is readonly ldap.
I have some questions/problems:

1. Is it possilble to skip the Consent Page? I have set 
               <SkipUserConsent>true</SkipUserConsent> 

   and tried *true* and *false* for 
           <EnableSSOConsentManagement>false</EnableSSOConsentManagement>

   in identity.xml, but this has no effect.
2. I want to send claims in the saml response as saml-attribute. I have
   enabled "Enable Attribute Profile" and "Include Attribute in the
   Response Always" in the Service Provider Configuration and use a
   custom Claim Dialect. But only the claims marked as Requested and
   Mandatory are send in the response. This seems to be a bug, since I
   expect all claims marked as requested to be send. It should be
   possible to send claims, which are optional (e.g. displayname)
3. I can perform a login with firefox and chrome as browser but when I
       use Internet Explorer, after entering my credentials, the saml attributes are not recognised: the page "Provide Mandatory Details"
   is shown. Is this a bug? (thats why I am interested in skipping the
   consent page)

Comment: I did some more tests  with the issue and now setting SkipUserConsent>false</SkipUserConsent> worked. But I am still interested in my second question. Thanks to Procinger for his advice.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, I set EnableSSOConsentManagement to "false" and it did not work.

It turned out that there were two identity.xml files:

```
repository/conf/identity.xml <- wrong file
repository/conf/identity/identity.xml <- correct file
```

After I set it in the right file, it worked well